# C++ template function that receives std::vector as argument

Tags: c++, c++11

I need to make a template function that receives as parameter a std::container of some type - let's say std::vector and deletes all elements from that container. I need a function equivalent to this:

```
for_each(some_vector.begin(), some_vector.end(), [](some_vector_type* element){delete element;});
```

The call should be something like:

```
delete_all_elements(some_vector);
```

Is this possible?

EDIT: I want to use first code inside delete_all_elements

Comment: You're using C++11 and still write `delete` ? Are you sure you can't make your problem disappear with `std::vector<std::unique_ptr<T>>` ?

Comment: As a bonus answer: If you delete some pointers, at the end: either put those deleted pointers to `NULL` (or C++11's `nullptr`), or remove those pointers from the container (unless you're sure the container itself is destroyed soon after). Having dangling pointers is not a good design choice... :-) ... Reading all answers, I'm surprised to read none will do that last bit of cleaning.

Comment: Another reason for using `std::unique_ptr` to vanish the problem is that when you want a vector of pointers to the first elements of arrays, instead of to single objects, you can switch to a vector of `std::unique_ptr<T[]>`. As you are you'd have to write a `delete_all_array_elements` function identical to `delete_all_elements` except for using `delete[]` instead of `delete`, and then call the right one without help from the type system.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Why wouldn't it be?

```
template <typename C>
void delete_all_elements(C& container) {
    std::for_each(
        container.begin(), container.end(),
        [](typename C::value_type ptr) { delete ptr; }
    );
    container.clear();
}
```

You can add e.g. `static_assert(std::is_pointer<typename C::value_type>::value, "Elements must be pointers");` at the beginning to ensure you won't try to delete non-pointers.

Comment: Thanks! I didn't know about C::value_type.

Comment: In this case I don' think it makes a difference. But it may be worth using `C::reference` as your default in this type of situation to prevent accidental copies when the code is changed.

Comment: If you're going to be passed the container reference, add a `container.clear()` to the end, so they're not left with a container of dangling pointers.

Answer (score 1):

Why not do something like virtually every STL algorithm:

```
template<typename Iterator>
void delete_all_elements(Iterator begin, Iterator end) {
    while (begin != end) {
        delete *begin;
        ++begin;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The canonical way is:

```
template <typename I>
void delete_all_elements(I begin, I end)
{
    for (; begin != end; ++begin) delete *begin;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Are you looking for this (C++03 solution):

```
template<typename Container>
void delete_all(const Container & c)
{
   typename Container::const_iterator begin = c.begin(), end = c.end();
   while ( begin != end ) { delete *begin; ++begin; }
}
```

Comment: You are evaluating `T::end()` at each iteration. For `std::list` or `std::set` containers, `end()` is not guaranteed to be O(1), making your function potentially costly at execution. I guess you should move the `end()` part in the for's initialization part to avoid that potential problem.

Comment: And I could be wrong, but accepting const containers for your "delete all" function is bad style: While legal, you are still semantically modifying the values inside the container (destroying the objects inside the container).

Comment: @paercebal: Hope, its okay now. And `const-ness` is no problem here. `const int *p = new int; delete p;` perfectly value!

Comment: `Hope, its okay now. And const-ness is no problem here. const int *p = new int; delete p; perfectly value!` : Yes, I know. This is why I wrote "While legal" in my comment. But semantically this is wrong because, no matter the indirection (here, a "double pointer"), each item of the container contains a value pointing to a valid object. In the end of the function, those values do not point anymore to valid objects (they were destroyed). Thus, in a way, you modified the container, which is what you promised you would not do by declaring it const in the function prototype.

Comment: Nawaz: It's not that it's illegal, but it's poor form, as the function implies it's not going to change the public contents of the data, but then proceeds to blast all of the pointers.

Comment: @paercebal: If you make this non-const, then you cannot call this function on const vector.

Comment: @Nawaz : `If you make this non-const, then you cannot call this function on const vector.` Of course! This is exactly the point: The point is not giving your function as much power as possible. The point is to make your interfaces (here, your function prototype) as clear as possible when the user looks at them: `const` is here to tell the user "I promise I won't touch your container's contents". And then, in the body, you destroy the vector's content. This means you **lie** to the user, which is semantically wrong.

Comment: @Dave S : `[...] but then proceeds to blast all of the pointers` : I like the **blast** verb. So true!... You are explaining in a few words what took me a full comment to explain... +1

Comment: @Nawaz, it's the difference between *bitwise* constness and *logical* constness. Your compiler enforces the former, but the latter leads to better design.

Comment: @paercebal: The C++03 standard requires `end` to be a constant time operation in all containers.

Comment: @David: It better be. It would feel rather stupid having to traverse a list at least twice to iterate over it (once simply to find the end) :)

Comment: @paercebal: semantically, it's not *necessarily* a good idea to confuse the elements in a vector (which are pointers) with the things that they point to. A `const vector<T*>` is like a `T *const`, in that the referand can be modified but the reference can't be reseated. You conflate things by pretending it should be like a `T const *const`, i.e. we should not modify the referand. In fact, C++ encourages these "lies" further, since you can delete a `T const *`. You are placing yourself at odds with the language, I don't think your case is compelling enough to say that this is *always* best.

Comment: Basically it depends on the usage of the vector - maybe the referred-to objects are logically "inside" the vector in some uses, but they certainly aren't inside it as far as the vector is concerned, and in some uses they won't be logically inside it either. However, the simple argument in favour of making the vector non-const is to say that this function shouldn't be as the questioner defines it, it should also `clear()` the vector. Argument ended ;-)

Comment: @David Rodríguez - dribeas : "The C++03 standard requires end to be a constant time operation in all containers." Oops, my bad. I must have confused it with the `size()` method, which is not guaranteed to be O(1)... So @Nawaz, I was wrong about my first comment.

Comment: @Steve Jessop : I disagree with you *(I believe, unless exception, one should not use the extra indirection to ignore/remove the const-ness)*, but I see and understand the logic of your point, so yes, argument ended... ^_^ ... As for clearing the container, we both agree on that point.